# Overlay image-height-divs with %-width over image in CSS only

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a layout for an image gallery. 
The user should have left/right buttons on the image to see the next image.

Currently I'm working on the basic layout.

Everything is fine, but..

## The Problem:

I can't figure how to adjust the height of the left/right buttons.

## How it should look like

```
|<------- Image width ------->|
______________________________
|         |          |        |     ^
|                             |     |
|         |  Image   |        |     |
|   <                    >    |     | Image height
|         |          |        |     | Overlay height
|                             |     |
|_________|__________|________|     v

    ^                    ^
Overlay              Overlay
```

## How it actually looks like

```
|<------- Image width ------->|
______________________________
|         |          |        |  ^   ^
|                             |  |   |
|         |  Image   |        |  |   |
|                             |  |   | Image height
|         |          |        |  |   |
|   <                    >    |  |   |
|_________|__________|________|  |   v
|                             |  |
|         |          |        |  | Overlay height
|                             |  |
|         |          |        |  |
|_________            ________|  v

    ^                    ^
Overlay              Overlay
```

## Code:

### This is my css

```
.dt5_gallery{
    z-index:1;
    background-color: greenyellow;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.dt5_gallery img{
    z-index: 10;
}

.dt5_gallery_button{
    z-index:20;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #FF000055;    
    padding: 10px;
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 40%;
    width: 40%;
}

.dt5_gallery_button_left{            
    text-align: left;
    left:0px;
}
.dt5_gallery_button_right {    
    text-align: right;
    left: calc(60%);    
}
```

### This is my html (`br`s are for showing the problem)

```
<div class="dt5_gallery">    
    <span class="dt5_gallery_button dt5_gallery_button_left">&#10094;</span>
        <img class="image" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9c/Apfel-Wellant.jpg/240px-Apfel-Wellant.jpg" />
    <span class="dt5_gallery_button dt5_gallery_button_right">&#10095;</span>
</div>

<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
```

## Fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/nebLjmy4/

Comment: I'm not so sure why you are making it complicated - many plugins out there offer a great carousel service, providing that's what you are going for.

Comment: True, @Dark Trick, you really want to do it in your way? if not there are many articles related to `carousel` does perfect job for you.

Comment: @David: As far as my research went, everything I found so far was lacking a specific property, that I wanted. And instead of searching hours for a "plugin", understand it's code base and then adjust it, I figured it's easier making my own. Also, I didn't come up with Manjuboyz keyword `carousel`, which might have speeded up the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some browsers (hello Safari!) doesn't like having `width` and `height` on `absolute` positioned elements. You need to contain the absolute elements by giving the parent `position: relative`, and you can center the child or text elements by making the absolute container a flex element. See comments in code below.

Your post didn't explain if the image should slide in or just replace the current image, so I assumed the later because it's easier to code. Hence, using `right` to create the width of the arrow containers.

```css
.dt5_gallery{
    z-index:1;
    background-color: greenyellow;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative; /* NEW */
}

.dt5_gallery img{
    z-index: 10;
}

.dt5_gallery_button{
    z-index:20;
    position: absolute;
    display: flex; /* NEW */
    align-items: center; /* NEW */
    background-color: #FF000055;    
    /* height: 100%; */
    /* padding-top: 40%; */
    padding: 10px;
    top: 0px; /* NEW */
    bottom: 0px; /* NEW */
}

.dt5_gallery_button_left{
    /* text-align: left; */
    left:0px;
    right: 60%;
}
.dt5_gallery_button_right {    
    /* text-align: right; */
    justify-content: right; /* NEW */
    right: 0px;
    left: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div class="dt5_gallery">    
    <span class="dt5_gallery_button dt5_gallery_button_left">&#10094;</span>
        <img class="image" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9c/Apfel-Wellant.jpg/240px-Apfel-Wellant.jpg" />
    <span class="dt5_gallery_button dt5_gallery_button_right">&#10095;</span>
</div>

<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `display: table` can help your layout

```
.dt5_gallery{
  background-color: greenyellow;
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
  text-align: center;
}

.image {
  display: table-cell;
}

.dt5_gallery_button{
  display: table-cell;
  background-color: #FF000055;
  z-index: 20;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 40%;
}
```

[Online Verification](https://jsfiddle.net/qw0ajsb9/)

Comment: This stops the buttons from overlaying the image, which is crucial.